# What's the right way to name an email attachment in .NET?

Tags: c#, email, header, attachment

There are 3 "name" properties on the .NET `Attachment` class:

`Attachment.Name`
`Attachment.ContentType.Name`
`Attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName`

I want to send an excel file with the name "foo.xls". Which of these should be set? What's the difference? The docs are not particularly illuminating.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think all of them are related to the `MIME Type`.

Comment: I don't think you need to set any of them. You just need to refer to the file when actually attaching it. ie: `Attachment data = new Attachment(file)`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MelanciaUK: I'm attaching a stream, not a file on the system

Comment: Got it. @Ntellect13 posted a good answer below.

Answer (score 4):

The correct one to use is Attachment.Name.

Info for Attachment.ContentType.Name -

When specifying content for a Attachment as a Stream or String, you can use Name to set the name of the file that stores the content on the recipient's system

Info for Attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName -

The FileName property allows the sender to **suggest** the name to be used to store an e-mail attachment on the recipient's computer. **This name is a suggestion only**; the receiving system can ignore it. The name must not include path information; any such information is ignored by the receiving computer.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the best thing to do would be to set both Attachment.Name and ContentDisposition.Name values to the same thing. Also, should ANY of these values include path information?

Comment: It would probably be best to include both although not required. This article ("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contentdisposition.filename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx") says that you should not include path information. If you do, it will just be ignored.

Comment: The other two really don't mention anything about a path being included although the example shows no path